# Why event and listeners not working on laravel 9?

Tags: events, listener, laravel-9

Got stuck with event and listeners.

EventServicePrivider:

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
        MessageSending::class => [
            MessageSendingListener::class,
        ],
        Purchased::class => [
            FacebookConversion::class,
        ],
    ];
}
```

Event class:

```
class Purchased
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $order;
    public $user;

    public function __construct(Order $order, User $user)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

Listener class:

```
class FacebookConversion
{
    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function handle(Purchased $event)
    {
        \Log::debug('not working');
    }
}
```

Calling event from controller (tried in different formats):

```
Purchased::dispatch($order, \Auth::user());
event(new Purchased($order, \Auth::user()));
Event::dispatch(new Purchased($order, \Auth::user()));
```

I do not get any errors. But nothing logged. Maybe i have missed something? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hah. I have just forgot to add these lines in EventServiceProvider.php, at the top:

```
use App\Events\Purchased;
use App\Listeners\FacebookConversion;
```